# Interpolate motion between motion track keyframes

Tags: animation, keyframes, constraints, tracking

I'm trying to get a simple 2d track from points on a finger. Sometimes the finger moves quickly and the tracker loses it for a few frames. Once the finger settles, I'll manually move the track back into place, so I'll essentially have 2 keyframes; before and after the blurry motion. Since I'll be constraining an empty to the tracking point, I'd like that motion in between interpolated. Just like any animation in blender using keyframes. Currently I've had to go frame by frame to add those points back in, even though the motion is directly vertical and a normal keyframe animation would do the trick.

So far the closest solution I've found is after linking my track to an empty, I click 'Constraint to F-curve', then clean up the keyframes in the graph editor. This isn't practical though for a long track.

I'm aware I could make my track settings better, which I'm working on, but would love to know if it's possible for blender to tween motion tracking points. I often 2d track in other software this way, and it saves a lot of time for simple tracks where only a few frames here and there are lost.

Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, the whole point of keyframes is to animate between them.  Haven't found a way to get Blender to acknowledge them yet.  Although sometimes it says "estimated" in the tracking info, but those frames don't seem to count.

Answer (score 1):

Tracking is an art. Perfect automatic tracking is hardly ever possible and will require some manual supervision and/or interpretation.

For a few frames you can manually move the tracking points in the tracking graph (that green and red graph that gives you the speed at which the trackcers are moving in the horizontal (red) and vertical (green) axis)

Other things to try: animate the settings for weight and stab weight. Or bring down the coorelation when tracking fast moving objects and bringing it up again when the motion slows down. And of course you can always use the clean-up tools in the solve tab.

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware dialing in my settings better will definitely help, just specifically trying to find a way for blender to fill frames in between my manual intervention. Basically as if I had the footage as a camera background, and then key framed an empty manually. Just would like to keep it in the motion tracker so I can get Blender to track where possible.